# Возможно ли задать горизонтальную ориентацию только для 10" устройств?

Tags: android

Имеется приложение, и хотелось бы добавить возможность смены ориентации, те загрузки другого layout только на 10". 
Как варианта только на 10"+.

Возможно ли сделать нечто подобное?
Если да, то подскажите пожалуйста какой метод использовать.

Comment: уточните, вы хотите разрешать поворачивать эран, только на 10" устройствах, или хотите, чтобы использовался особый landscape layout только на 10" устройствах?ъ

Comment: @metalurgus хочу использовался особый landscape layout только на 10" устройствах.

Comment: @metalurgus простите, немного сам запутался. Я хочу разрешить поворачивать экран только на 10" устройствах и при этом использовать особый landscape layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для 10"+ `10-inch tablet` используйте модификатор для ресурсов **-xlarge** или **-sw800**
API 13+

Вам необходимо запретить смену ориентации для всех устройств, кроме:

Создайте папку с ресурсами аналогично выше к примеру values-sw800 и values-xlarge, поместите туда флаг boolean:

```
<bool name="orientation_portrait">false</bool>
```

При пуске вставьте кусок кода пример:

```
if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.orientation_portrait)) setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Получится что только при пуске, устройства 10"+ будет возможно смена ориентации на land, иначе only portrait. Не забудьте только в default values, добавить ресурс тоже: только true.

Comment: можно уточнить? Выходит что для 10" мне достаточно добавить папку `layout-sw800` с заранее заданными стилями и при смене ориентации будет загружена именно она?

Comment: layout-sw800-land, при смене ориентации, будет подтягиваться папка с этим ресурсом, но вы не запретите смену ориентации, для других случаев. 
Поэтому нужен другой подход, я сразу не понял суть вопроса, только после вашего последнего коммента, сейчас добавлю